# group array of object in new properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

```
[{date:'2017-8-1'},{date:'2017-8-2'},{date:'2017-8-3'},{date:'2017-8-5'},{date:'2017-8-6'},{date:'2017-8-7'},{date:'2017-8-8'},{date:'2017-8-9'}]
```

I have above data, I try to group the last 2 item and give it a property 'weekend', and the rest is 'weekday', my expected out put is like this

```
{
    weekdays: [{date:'2017-8-1'},{date:'2017-8-2'},{date:'2017-8-3'},{date:'2017-8-5'},{date:'2017-8-6'},{date:'2017-8-7'}],
    weekends: [{date:'2017-8-8'},{date:'2017-8-9'}]
}
```

I had a failed attempt

```
data.map((obj, i) => {

    if(data.length - (i + 1) >= 2) {
        return {
            weekdays: {
                date: moment(obj.date)
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        weekends: {
            date: moment(obj.date)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're not sure what order the days will be in:

```js
days = [{date:'2017-8-1'},{date:'2017-8-2'},{date:'2017-8-3'},{date:'2017-8-5'},{date:'2017-8-6'},{date:'2017-8-7'},{date:'2017-8-8'},{date:'2017-8-9'}]

const isWeekend = day => (
  [6, 0].includes(new Date(day.date).getDay())
);

const separate = (days) => {
  const weekends = [];
  const weekdays = [];
  days.forEach((day) => {
    isWeekend(day) ? weekends.push(day) : weekdays.push(day);
  });
  return { weekends, weekdays };
};

console.log(separate(days));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure the weekend days are always the last two element in the input array, you could do with a simple `slice`.

```js
var inputArray = [{date:'2017-8-1'},{date:'2017-8-2'},{date:'2017-8-3'},{date:'2017-8-5'},{date:'2017-8-6'},{date:'2017-8-7'},{date:'2017-8-8'},{date:'2017-8-9'}],
outputArray = {
  weekdays: inputArray.slice(0,5),
  weekends: inputArray.slice(6)
};

console.log(outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert strings into dates and then use `.getDay()` method to check what day it is. Then just put it into corresponding arrays like this:

```js
var array = [{date:'2017-8-1'},{date:'2017-8-2'},{date:'2017-8-3'},{date:'2017-8-5'},{date:'2017-8-6'},{date:'2017-8-7'},{date:'2017-8-8'},{date:'2017-8-9'}];
var obj = {
    weekdays: [],
    weekends: []
};

array.forEach((el, key) => {
    if(new Date(el.date).getDay() === 0 || new Date(el.date).getDay() === 6) obj.weekends.push(el); else obj.weekdays.push(el);
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are neither returning to a variable nor returning an array. 
Try using foreach and add your properties to a variable.

instead of your current solution, try this ;

```
newOb = {};
Array.forEach((o,i)=>{
If(i>(array.length-2)-1){
newOb.weekend == undefined? newOb.weekend=[o]:newOb.weekend.push(o);}
else{
newOb.weekday == undefined? newOb.weekday = [o]: newOb.weekday.push(o);}});
```

Comment: Your answer is good but not enough, better post a code sample

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers and explain why your attempt failed: This is a case for `Array.reduce` rather than `Array.map`. The latter is designed to return one element for each element in the input array, while `reduce` can be used to "fold" an array into a single value, object or something else (which is what we want).

An elegant solution could look like this:

```
const outObj = inArr.reduce(function(obj, current, i) {
    if(i >= 5) { // or other check for weekend, depending on your data
      return Object.assign(obj, { weekends : obj.weekends.push(current) })
    } else {
      return Object.assign(obj, { weekdays : obj.weekdays.push(current) })
    }
  }, { weekdays : [], weekends : [] })
```

In the code snippet above, the function that we pass in is run on each input element, like with `map`. The crucial difference is that it can access the output that was produced by the last run of the function, which is passed in as first parameter (called `obj` in this example). The second parameter that is passed to `reduce`, by the way, is the initial state of `obj` (an object with two empty lists).

This approach makes it possible to gradually fill up a single object rather than creating *n* different ones, like your `map` version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [momenjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) already then you can convert your array to the array of `moment` objects using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then simply [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) using [`isoWeekday()` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weekday/):

```js
var array = [{date:'2017-8-1'},{date:'2017-8-2'},{date:'2017-8-3'},{date:'2017-8-5'},{date:'2017-8-6'},{date:'2017-8-7'},{date:'2017-8-8'},{date:'2017-8-9'}];

var momentArray = array.map(function(d){ return moment(d.date, "YYYY-M-D"); });

var obj = {
    weekdays: momentArray.filter(function(d){ return d.isoWeekday() < 6 }),
    weekends: momentArray.filter(function(d){ return d.isoWeekday() > 5 })
};

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```